# How do I store 2 parameters with JQuery.data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following js:

```
$('.overview_table_header').click(function() {
  header = $(this)
  $.get("/sort", { col: $.trim($(this).text()), sort: header.data('sort') },
    function(data) {
      $('#pages').html(data.html);
      header.data('sort', data.sort);
    }
  );
});
```

Which passes 2 parameters (A get request to /sort): `{"col"=>"DATA", "sort"=>"OTHERDATA"}`

I'm new to JQuery and Ajax. How do I store The above DATA and OTHERDATA in a hidden field tag within my html? Is using [JQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) the best method to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.data() is what I would use. You can do:

```
$(header).data({"col":"DATA", "sort":"OTHERDATA"});
```

or

```
$(header).data("col","DATA");
$(header).data("sort","OTHERDATA");
```

Comment: 'header 'can be replaced with a reference to whatever element you want to store the data in.

Comment: can you show me that. I don't want to use the header reference. I'd like to store it in a hidden field if thats possible

Comment: I'm unclear where you're asking for. What do you mean my hidden field? How do you intend to access the data later?

Comment: The problem is I am using a Ruby will_paginate plugin (ruby) with a JQuery/Ajax sorting. When I paginate, I lose the sort. I want to store this sorting data in an HTML element; paginate; then extract the stored data to maintain my sort. I can't access the data in header.